# iPhone App Minus App Store?

Tags: ios, iphone

If I create an application on my Mac, is there any way I can get it to run on an iPhone without going through the app store?

It doesn't matter if the iPhone has to be jailbroken, as long as I can still run an application created using the official SDK. For reasons I won't get into, I can't have this program going through the app store.

Comment: As of Xcode 7, it is now possible to run an app on a connected device without signing up for a developer account or jailbreaking the device. [See this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33928777/3681880) for details.

Comment: You can use **AppBox**, A mac application that uses your dropbox account to distribute you ad-hoc and enterprise apps. Give it a try here https://github.com/vineetchoudhary/AppBox-iOSAppsWirelessInstallation/releases

Answer (score 187, accepted):

## Official Developer Program

For a standard iPhone you'll need to pay the US$99/yr to be a member of the developer program. You can then use the adhoc system to install your application onto up to 100 devices. The developer program has the details but it involves adding UUIDs for each of the devices to your application package. UUIDs can be easiest retrieved using [Ad Hoc Helper](http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=285691333&mt=8) available from the App Store. For further details on this method, see Craig Hockenberry's [Beta testing on iPhone 2.0](http://furbo.org/2008/08/06/beta-testing-on-iphone-20/) article

## Jailbroken iPhone

For jailbroken iPhones, you can use the following method which I have personally tested using the [AccelerometerGraph](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/index.html) sample app on iPhone OS 3.0.

### Create Self-Signed Certificate

First you'll need to create a self signed certificate and patch your iPhone SDK to allow the use of this certificate:

1. Launch Keychain Access.app. With no items selected, from the Keychain menu select Certificate Assistant, then Create a Certificate.

   Name: iPhone Developer
   Certificate Type: Code Signing
   Let me override defaults: Yes
2. Click Continue

   Validity: 3650 days
3. Click Continue
4. Blank out the Email address field.
5. Click Continue until complete.

   You should see "This root certificate is not trusted". This is expected.
6. Set the iPhone SDK to allow the self-signed certificate to be used:

   > sudo /usr/bin/sed -i .bak 's/XCiPhoneOSCodeSignContext/XCCodeSignContext/' /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Info.plist

   If you have Xcode open, restart it for this change to take effect.

### Manual Deployment over WiFi

The following steps require `openssh`, and `uikittools` to be installed first. Replace `jasoniphone.local` with the hostname of the target device.  Be sure to set your own password on both the `mobile` and `root` users after installing SSH.

To manually compile and install your application on the phone as a system app (bypassing Apple's installation system):

1. Project, Set Active SDK, Device and Set Active Build Configuration, Release.
2. Compile your project normally (using Build, not Build & Go).
3. In the `build/Release-iphoneos` directory you will have an app bundle. Use your preferred method to transfer this to /Applications on the device.

   > `scp -r AccelerometerGraph.app root@jasoniphone:/Applications/`
4. Let SpringBoard know the new application has been installed:

   > `ssh mobile@jasoniphone.local uicache`

   This only has to be done when you add or remove applications. Updated applications just need to be relaunched.

To make life easier for yourself during development, you can setup SSH key authentication and add these extra steps as a custom build step in your project.

Note that if you wish to remove the application later you cannot do so via the standard SpringBoard interface and you'll need to use SSH and update the SpringBoard:

```
ssh root@jasoniphone.local rm -r /Applications/AccelerometerGraph.app &&
ssh mobile@jasoniphone.local uicache
```

Comment: Mine will not build - Xcode immediately gives a code signing error as soon as I try to build...

Comment: @Rev316 `uicache` should be there if you have the `uikittools` package installed.

Comment: I'm follow you but met this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161877/iphone-problem-when-deploy-to-real-device-the-identity-used-to-sign-the-execut

Comment: Also, you want to set up a private/public key pair over ssh to make things passwordless

Comment: is there a way to make it removable like a regular app? by the way, there's another option rather than installing ssh, using regular USB build with AppSync: http://www.alexwhittemore.com/?p=398&cpage=4#comment-5313

Comment: @Cawas Yes you can, just get CyDelete from cydia... Currently I am getting this error on iOS 4.2 (just a warning):  `Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)` any help with this?

Comment: @Richard I should have said I'm aware of CyDelete. I meant really **like a regular app**... Tho it's probably irrelevant, it's just a curiosity on how would it be done. About your issue, have you tried doing every step? I've made a guide mixing Alex's and Jason's in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-real-iphone-device/4180498#4180498

Comment: @cawas... please look at my answer, it will install as a normal app.

Comment: What about the provisioning profile? Is there a way to get one without subscribing to the developer program?

Comment: @TeodorKostov As of 2015, the answer is still NO.  You can develop in simulator, and (now) attach a device (e.g. an iPhone) via USB and install app on that for testing (app expires in 60 or 90 days). But no ability to sign for distribution, without joining developer program.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, once you have joined the iPhone Developer Program, and paid Apple $99, you can provision your applications on up to 100 iOS devices.

Comment: Why is there a 100 install limit?

Comment: So people can't use this as a way to bypass the App store entirely.

Comment: And the 100 limit is counted as the number of devices you have registered that year on the iOS Provisioning Portal, not the current number you have.   So if you add 5 devices and then delete all 5, you have 95 (not 100) more devices you may add.

Comment: But the number of devices used resets once you renew your developer program.

Comment: And the ad-hoc provisioning profiles expire in 3 months so you can't permanently distribute apps even to the limited (100) set of devices you have registered.

Answer (score 13):

- Build your app
- Upload to a crack site
- (If you app is good enough) the crack version will be posted minutes later and ready for everyone to download ;-)

Answer (score 8):

With the help of [this post](http://www.iphonedevx.com/?p=59), I have made a script that will install via the app Installous for rapid deployment:

```
# compress application.
/bin/mkdir -p $CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/Payload
/bin/cp -R $CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/MyApp.app $CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/Payload
/bin/cp iTunesCrap/logo_itunes.png $CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/iTunesArtwork
/bin/cp iTunesCrap/iTunesMetadata.plist $CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/iTunesMetadata.plist

cd $CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR

# zip up the HelloWorld directory

/usr/bin/zip -r MyApp.ipa Payload iTunesArtwork iTunesMetadata.plist
```

What Is missing in the post referenced above, is the iTunesMetadata. Without this, Installous will not install apps correctly. Here is an example of an iTunesMetadata:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>appleId</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>artistId</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>artistName</key>
    <string>MYCOMPANY</string>
    <key>buy-only</key>
    <true/>
    <key>buyParams</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>copyright</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>drmVersionNumber</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>fileExtension</key>
    <string>.app</string>
    <key>genre</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>genreId</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>itemId</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>itemName</key>
    <string>MYAPP</string>
    <key>kind</key>
    <string>software</string>
    <key>playlistArtistName</key>
    <string>MYCOMPANY</string>
    <key>playlistName</key>
    <string>MYAPP</string>
    <key>price</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>priceDisplay</key>
    <string>nil</string>
    <key>rating</key>
    <dict>
        <key>content</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>label</key>
        <string>4+</string>
        <key>rank</key>
        <integer>100</integer>
        <key>system</key>
        <string>itunes-games</string>
    </dict>
    <key>releaseDate</key>
    <string>Sunday, December 12, 2010</string>
    <key>s</key>
    <integer>143441</integer>
    <key>softwareIcon57x57URL</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>softwareIconNeedsShine</key>
    <false/>
    <key>softwareSupportedDeviceIds</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </array>
    <key>softwareVersionBundleId</key>
    <string>com.mycompany.myapp</string>
    <key>softwareVersionExternalIdentifier</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>softwareVersionExternalIdentifiers</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1466803</integer>
        <integer>1529132</integer>
        <integer>1602608</integer>
        <integer>1651681</integer>
        <integer>1750461</integer>
        <integer>1930253</integer>
        <integer>1961532</integer>
        <integer>1973932</integer>
        <integer>2026202</integer>
        <integer>2526384</integer>
        <integer>2641622</integer>
        <integer>2703653</integer>
    </array>
    <key>vendorId</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>versionRestrictions</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Obviously, replace all instances of MyApp with the name of your app and MyCompany with the name of your company.

Basically, this will install on any jailbroken device with Installous installed. After it is set up, this results in very fast deployment, as it can be installed from anywhere, just upload it to your companies website, and download the file directly to the device, and copy / move it to `~/Documents/Installous/Downloads`.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I doubt it, but seeing as now you can side-load iOS Apps  with any apple ID for free, I don't see the need for it.

Answer (score 7):

With the upcoming Xcode 7 it's now possible to install apps on your devices without an apple developer license, so now it is possible to *skip* the app store and you don't have to jailbreak your device.

> **Now everyone can get their app on their Apple device.**
>
> Xcode 7 and
> Swift now make it easier for everyone to build apps and run them
> directly on their Apple devices. Simply sign in with your Apple ID,
> and turn your idea into an app that you can touch on your iPad,
> iPhone, or Apple Watch. Download Xcode 7 beta and try it yourself
> today. Program membership is not required.

Quoted from: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

**Update:**

XCode 7 is now released:

> **Free On-Device Development**
> Now everyone can run and test their own app
> on a device—for free. You can run and debug your own creations on a
> Mac, iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, or Apple Watch without any fees, and no
> programs to join. All you need to do is enter your free Apple ID into
> Xcode. You can even use the same Apple ID you already use for the App
> Store or iTunes. Once you’ve perfected your app the Apple Developer
> Program can help you get it on the App Store.
>
> See [Launching Your App on Devices](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH27) for detailed information about
> installing and running on devices.

Answer (score 4):

It's worth noting that if you go the jailbroken route, it's possible (likely?) that an iPhone OS update would kill your ability to run these apps. I'd go the official route and pay the $99 to get authorized. In addition to not having to worry about your apps being clobbered, you also get the opportunity (should you choose) to release your apps on the store.

Answer (score 2):

After copying the the app to the iPhone in the way described by @Jason Weathered, make sure to "chmod +x" of the app, otherwise it won't run.

Answer (score 1):

*Changes/Notes to make this work for **Xcode 3.2.1** and **iPhone SDK 3.1.2**

Manual Deployment over WiFi

2) Be sure to restart Xcode after modifying the Info.plist

3) The "uicache" command is not found, using killall -HUP SpringBoard worked fine for me.

Other then that, I can confirm this works fine.

Mac users, using PwnageTool 3.1.4 worked great for Jailbreaking (DL via torrent).

Comment: Ah. Thanks Jason, Appreciate the well documented post! May want to mention installing Cydia's UIKit Tools package for Jailbreak nubs like myself.

Answer (score 1):

If you patch `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Info.plist` and then try to debug a application running on the device using a real development provisionen profile from Apple it will probably not work. Symptoms are weird error messages from `com.apple.debugserver` and that you can use any bundle identifier without getting a error when building in Xcode. The solution is to restore `Info.plist`.