# Xcode 3.1.4 missing Code Signing Entitlements Options?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am on Xcode 3.1.4 and hitting the dreaded ""the executable was signed with invalid entitlements." error.

I am trying to add Entitlement.plist in the BUILD option but I cannot find where to put it.

This option used to exist above the "Code Signing Identity". I think it was called "Code Signing Entitlement" or something.

Is this missing in your version of xcode 3.1.4 ?

Answer (score 7):

SOLVED.

Inside the Target Build Settings->Architecture, Make sure your Base SDK is set to Device and not Simulator.

Answer (score 2):

I could not find the Code Signing Entitlements option in In XCode 4 either...but after staring empty at the screen for about two hours, I did.

If you highlight your project, then select the target of interest and then finally switch from  "Basic" to "All", you will find it.

Answer (score 1):

Nice one, solved my problem too.

Its in the project menu at the bottom "edit active target", or press ALT+CMD+E

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and my base SDK was set to "iPhone Device 2.0 (missing)". Changing it to "iPhone Device 2.2.1" fixed the above, and a number of other odd things that were happening.

Thanks user82383!