# iPhone Development Developer Program and a Client

Tags: iphone

**Note:** I have given up on compiling iPhone Apps without a developer certificate for the SDK 3.x... for now. But [it wasn't for a lack of trying.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357731/self-signing-code-in-xcode-for-iphone) Anyway...

I work for a client who will will be making iPhone Apps but will **not** deliver them through the AppStore for the time being. I will be testing and deploying iPhone apps to a device I own, and they will need to distribute to their iPhones/iPod Touches. If I buy a $99 developer certificate, will that be enough to distribute an app onto iPhones that are **not** connected to my computer?

**If not, how can this be done for testing -- distributing to other iPhones -- with the least number of certificates?** [I have checked this out a bit](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices/devices.html), but I haven't been able to fully undertand it (I'm kind of busy trying to learn to program for the iPhone :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282018/iphone-app-beta-testing-on-specific-device-before-app-goes-to-appstore/2282072#2282072.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use an Ad Hoc distribution certificate (available as part of the $99 program). This will enable you to install on up to 100 devices. To install all the user needs is a device with the correct provisioning profile and iTunes (Mac or PC)

Answer (score 1):

Purchasing the $99 iPhone Developer Program will give you the ability to create ad hoc builds which will be able to run on up to 100 provisioned devices.