# Is this possible to run the app with a binary file with no iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone

I want to give my app to others, but they don't have the iPhone SDK.  if I give the binary file of my app, is it possible that they can run the app on their device?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you beta test an iphone app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154/how-do-you-beta-test-an-iphone-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

others can only run your app if your app has a `Provisioning Profile` with the [UDID](http://www.tuaw.com/2008/08/08/iphone-101-find-udid-with-a-single-click/) of their iphone in it. For a pre release you can generate an `AdHoc Provisioning Profile` in the iPhone Provisioning Portal, which you can only access as a iphone developer