# Problem while loading the application on iPad?

Tags: ipad

I developed a simple application for iPad.
I want to test the app how it works on the device.
I have paid developer licence, and i have added the device id and created the app id and i have downloaded the provisioning profile using both.

The same way how we will build the app for iphone i have done for ipad.

i have sent the provisioning profile and .ipa file to my friend to load on to the ipad device(same device which i have added in the developer.apple.com).

when he tried to drag n drop the provisioning file on to the device from iTunes it is giving below error.

**"abc.mobileprovision" was not copied on to the iPad, because it cannot be palyed on this iPad**

I am not able to understand what the exact error is.
Can anyone please let me know how to dump the applicatio on to the ipad device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mobileprovision file should be dropped into the Library group, not the device.

http://a.ifimg.com/images/howto/install-iphone-application-ad-hoc-distribution/winxp-itunes-add-mobileprovision-profile.01.png?1273524047

See [How do you beta test an iphone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154/how-do-you-beta-test-an-iphone-app/2426270#2426270) for a detailed instruction.

Comment: thank you for the reply.
one things i didnot understood from the link which you have given is selecting "Distribution" under Active configuration tab.
till now i am using "Release" under this.

the installation procedure which we are using for iphone will work well for ipad also? or there is any other way?
because i am getting the above error ""abc.mobileprovision" was not copied on to the iPAD, because it cannot be palyed on this iPAD

"?

Comment: @chaitanya: Both iPhone and iPad should be the same. You're getting the above error probably because iTunes thinks that file is a song.

Comment: ya ...
can you suggest any way to avoid this problem?
can you let me one thing that, after connect the device to itunes, to where exactly we need to drag and drop the files( which tab)?

Comment: Same thing i am doing kenny..
but still i am getting same error..
do you know anything about this?

Comment: Maybe things have changed now but in iTunes 12, there is no Library group.