# Converting source to binary

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I dont want to give my code to my client, i just want to give him binary. How can i create such binary that client can test using XCode and iphone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you beta test an iphone app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154/how-do-you-beta-test-an-iphone-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your client an AdHoc build. You need to add his / her device ID to the profile. Check iPhone Developer Program User Guide published by Apple for detail steps.