# iOS: how to distribute a "parallel" app version for ad-hoc beta testing

Tags: xcode, ios, adhoc, beta-testing

I'd like to start doing limited beta testing of an iOS app. I know how to do regular ad-hoc distribution of my existing app, but I've had one of my potential beta users tell me that when they test other apps, they end up having a separate app installed alongside the production one. But I don't know what the other developers are doing to create this.

Do I need to burn up a fresh app ID registered with Apple (and app name that will never be real) to accomplish this for my beta users?

If so, is there a reasonable way to manage this within a single Xcode project?

Thanks from anyone with experience here. I know I'm toying with the line of "programming question", but this is certainly the community with the right expertise. Thanks! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154/how-do-you-beta-test-an-iphone-app

Comment: Thanks, but not a dupe. I know how to do ad-hoc distribution. I'd like to know how to do it with a "parallel" app.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just set a different bundle identifier in your Info.plist.

Personally, I create three configurations in my project (Debug, Ad Hoc, App Store) and then define a user-defined build setting for each config (`BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER`) in which I set the different bundle IDs.

In my Info.plist, I can then set the bundle ID as `${BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}`.

Comment: So some other bundle identifier but using a certificate with the same app ID is OK?

Comment: I am actually not sure. I usually use my wildcard app id (`.*`) for my Ad Hoc build and a regular custom App ID for the App Store build. But I think it shouldn't matter either way (unless you use features that are identified via the App ID, i.e. Push Notifications, Game Center, ...).

Comment: Thanks for the added detail here.

Comment: Works like a champ. Thanks Ole.