# testflightapp.com, how it works, and can I assume it is safe and work longer?

Tags: ios, testing, distribution

I heard and tried testflightapp.com and I surprised. Because only by installing their profiling with a few taps, iOS allowed installing apps from them. I have shocked. Is this normal? How are they work? And can I assume them as safe and work longer without any accidental service shutdown? (such as sued by Apple...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to use your own AdHoc distribution profiles, nothing changed there. The profile you can install via their website is only for submitting the UDID to the website.

This question is already answered here: [How does TestFlight do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973244/how-does-testflight-do-it)

Answer (score 1):

It's a standard way to distribute your apps introduced with iOS 4. "All" that Testflight did was build a webapp and community around it.