# installing ipa file from the app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ipa

I want to install a new version of same app from the application inside and after n days of installing app.

Suppose user install app.then after 10 days he will get a prompt that your app want to install new version and then if he allow new version get installed.

it's not for app store submission.

I want to keep new verion of ipa in iPhone local memory or main bundle

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can install an app directly from an IPA inside another app.  You can install one over-the-air though, so you might be able to do it by running a web server right on the device and serving the IPA through the web server.  It's going to be complicated.  Start by reading through the answers to this question:

[How does TestFlight do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973244/how-does-testflight-do-it)

Comment: Note that this won't work for applications installed via the App Store.

Comment: He said “it's not for app store submission.”