# Programmatically installing enterprise Apps in IOS

Tags: ios, enterprise

I'm currently working at a company which is thinking about getting an enterprise app store. They asked me to build an little Proof of Concept to see how things could be working. I have already some basic ideas about the processes that need to be out in place and so on. But since I've never done mobile App development I'm a little stuck. I'm currently searching the internet for information about how to install Enterprise Apps but all i find is how to do it by using iTunes.

I need a solution in which i can install mobile Apps programatically over a web site. Or Over one App that is installed on the device (initial app could be installed over iTunes)... Does anyone of you have any information about the installation procedure and would share it. Or does maybe anyone have some good links to online resources or could point me in the right direction.

Thanks a lot
Sulo

Answer (score 1):

Just use TestFlight for that, it's awesome. http://www.testflightapp.com

It let's you install app's on device with just one click, notify testers,etc

Read this [How does TestFlight do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973244/how-does-testflight-do-it)

Answer (score 0):

From memory there were WWDC videos about this topic.  Check both the WWDC 2010 and WWDC 2011 videos here:

[WWDC Videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/)

Unfortunately, I can't remember in which video the topic of Enterprise Apps and how to install them over the web was discussed.  Sorry - there are a lot of videos.