# iphone: enterprise account build

Tags: ipad, enterprise

My client give me his enterprise account to build in-house application for his company. He would like to deploy about 200 ipad devices. Is there a way I can build final build without knowing all UDIDs of those devices. Because that would be a time-consume task for my client to collect all over 200 ipad devices.

I would like to build and upload it to one link. All ipads will get ipa from that link and install to each devices.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`TestFlight` offers over-the-air beta distribution of iOS apps, might be that is usefull for you. Testflight use enterprise distribution mechanism.

Following is the link of testflight - testflightapp.com

You can check Kerni's answer in this thread for other options which are available - [How does TestFlight do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973244/how-does-testflight-do-it)