# How to create a beta test server like TestFlight?

Tags: iphone, testflight

I want to create my own test server for iPhone apps, because uploading big apps to TestFlight costs too much time. 
My question is : if I build an IPA with development provisioning profile, put it on my own server, could users download and install it with iOS devices from my server? If users can, is there any special thing to do to archive this?

And how to collect device info like TestFlight running in iOS's safari does?

Comment: Try out http://hockeykit.net It's open source, so you can find out how they do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although they're not a how-to, the answers to this Stack Overflow question should sort you out with most things you need to know, I expect:

- [How does TestFlight do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973244/how-does-testflight-do-it)