# How can I send my iOS app to my client for them to use it?

Tags: ios, xcode, titanium-mobile

I've been developing an app using Titanium Appcelerator, until now I've been previewing it using the iOS Simulator and my iPhone.

Now, I want to send my app to the client so they can use it on their iPhone. **How can I do this?**

Bear in mind this is my first iOS app and so I am not fully au-fait with the terminology or process in making an app go live.

Comment: I can recommend TestFlightApp.com

Comment: testflightapp.com - not absolutely sure it will work with Appcelerator, but that's what I use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Apple provided mechanism for achieving this, however apps like TestFlight provide a good mechanism for this. You have to register your clients device in order to allow them to install your app. Yes, this should work for Titanium.

You can find out how TestFlight works here:

[How does TestFlight do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973244/how-does-testflight-do-it)

Comment: actually, everything TestFlightApp uses is stock standard functionality of the provisioning system and documented by apple. They just package it up nicely.

Comment: I can confirm that TestFlight is the way to go

Comment: have been using Testflight to push build to clients for testing and it works as intended