# Upload ios development build app

Tags: ios, iphone, build

Diawi link expires in 10 days of upload? Do we have any other option for uploading development ios builds of iphone. Test flight is one of the option, but I am not getting that for what time it remains valid.

Answer (score 1):

http://hockeyapp.net/ is one of the other way of uploading apps, but I don't know about the time it remains valid. You can also have a look at [How does TestFlight do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973244/how-does-testflight-do-it). These might help you.