# iOS Remote Debugging on external Devices

Tags: xcode, ios, debugging

I am not sure if I can remote debug an application running on an Iphone which is not next to me? We test your app. well but some users have issues sometimes we can not replicate and dont know where to start digging in this cases. So it would be very easy for us when we can just connect the remote debugger via the internet to an device. Is is possible somehow?
Most of the guys using the app we could remote to there PCs (but the majority dont uses macs...) and run tools there, is this maybe an easier solution?

For Mac Os I found this http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/300-Debugging_Programs_Remotely/remote_debugging.html
But this is not for iOS...

Thx very very much already

Comment: Are the answers in this question very helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154

Answer (score 4):

Our company just released a service exactly for that purpose: http://apphance.com . It allows you to very easily (5 minutes) integrate your application - add framework project basically and you get all the remote debugging capability included (you can access everything from very nice web panel):

- You can see logs of running application (in near-real-time)
- You can see how device conditions change over time (rotation, wifi/gprs, battery, others)
- You get crashes reported to you automatically with all relevant information
- Even out-of-memory errors are reported
- Your testers can even report problems by shaking the device - including automated screenshots
- and more.....

It's currently, closed beta stage but you can request access and for sure you get it.

Comment: This is all lovely and everything and you got my hopes up in your first line, but it's not actually a debugger, right? It's all sorts of useful low level analytics, logs and crash dumps, but it's not a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is get the crash log(you can get this at any time through the Xcode Organizer or iTunes Connect in released Applications) symbolicate it and ask the tester what they did to cause the error. This will give you every piece of info you could of gotten from GDB.

Comment: Hello RTS, thx much for your fast answer. Unfo. the app dont crash just hangs sort off. So I can not get into the crash logs, or there other logs doing the same stuff as the GDB? Also i did not knew that the crash logs will be auto. uploaded to the itunes connect. where will i find them there? Sorry we are new to the Ios dev. part (coming from windows) and we app. any sort of help. thx very much!

Comment: just found the crash reports, but maybe this is not what i need, and its tels me there are no reports available for now...

Comment: 2day the first crash reports came in and perfect that will help us so much! I whanted to vote for ur solution but it does not allow me du to i am not registered... Anyway it looks like not all crash reports are show there can i manual merge .dsym with an .crsh?

Comment: And if it does not crash?

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://testflightapp.com/sdk/, you can get crash reports, remote logs, see how is the teststing going and much more, see link for further details.