# iOS Interactive Remote Debugging

Tags: ios, xcode, gdb, lldb

**Is it possible to interactively remote debug an iOS App with xCode** (or some other interactive debugger, if necessary)?

Has anyone got a neat framework I can stick in my App that will allow this? I can imagine Apple might not want this for live Apps, but for enterprise deployment and for Beta deployment, it would be ace.

A workflow that might work is a customer with a bug can get in touch and then I can email them with a link that will launch my app and connect it to my debug server. With magic.

There's an [S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5178307/2547229) from back in '11 about this – I'm hoping things might have moved on. However, [a post here](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Debugging_on_iOS_7) suggests it's probably not possible.

I want to be clear **crash reporting, log acquiring and analytics** are all very nice and everything (you're right – I use them too), but **that is not what this question is about**. Thank you :-)

Definitive answers along the lines of "This is just not possible because …" or, "It's possible but fearsomely involved because …", or ideally "Yeah, it's easy and cool, check out …" would be wonderful.

Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Debugserver) looks relevant, but it seems involved and unsupported.

Comment: From that link, this also looks relevant – https://speakerdeck.com/steipete/taking-advantage-of-the-runtime

Comment: [Pony Debugger](http://www.artandlogic.com/blog/2013/02/inspecting-ios-apps-with-ponydebugger/) is also not a real debugger, but does look very useful. From that page it will "allow you to inspect NSURLConnection based network activity, Core Data managed object contexts, and your view hierarchy remotely while your application is running."

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are searching is not possible. If you want, take a look at [Bugfender](http://bugfender.com), it's a product we have built that helps somewhat to do what you want.

With Bugfender you can get the logs from a remote device you choose, is not remote debugging but for now it might be the closest thing to what you want.