# Create installation package in MonoDevelop

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you beta test an iphone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154/how-do-you-beta-test-an-iphone-app)

How can I create an installation package for my iPad application so I can give it to my client so he can install it without my intervention?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154/how-do-you-beta-test-an-iphone-app

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to install iOS apps

1. Enterprise distribution
2. App Store distribution
3. Ad-Hoc via iTunes
4. Ad-Hoc via wireless

Excluding jailbroken devices, those are the only ways you can distribute an app.