# iPhone app code signing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I recently finished my first app for iPhone, I'm really new in programming and Xcode has lots of options that I can't understand. :(

I want to send my app to beta testers. When I archive my app and try to intall it with iTunes, I get a message like this: "The application  has not been installen because the authorizations are not valid." (I get the message in spanish and I just translated it)

I think it's because of the code sign but I don't really understand what are the differences are among the options:

http://cl.ly/0H2z011j0f2x3e0K2t3h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just submitted my first app last night as well. I had NO clue how to do it other than it "was going to be a pain".

The good news, I have an account with Lynda.com and they have a chapter that is all video tutorials on how to submit the app. It collectively is about a 30 minute chapter with video demos of EXACTLY what to do. Step by step. They offer a free 7 day trial. I cannot recommend you watch this chapter highly enough. Its a MUST see for a first time submission. And no, I do not work for them or associated to them what so ever. They just have a great product and I do not hesitate to recommend them.
After you submit you can cancel your account before being charged.

You can see an example of how they teach w/videos by clicking the link below.

http://www.lynda.com/iOS-SDK-4-tutorials/distributing-ios-applications-through-the-app-store/77853-2.html

They will allow you to watch 1 or two videos, but must sign up on the trial version to see the rest of them.

Trial version link:
http://www.lynda.com/promo/trial/Default.aspx?lpk35=1854

Happy coding! :)

Comment: People often say Lynda sucks, and they look useless to me as Apple's documentation is terrific. But that's what others say, I have no opinion.

Comment: I can agree that Lynda.com does lack in some areas, but as I said above.. when it comes to help submitting an app in the app store "I cannot recommend you watch this CHAPTER highly enough.". If anything just watch that chapter and cancel trial if you dont think Lynda can help in any other way.

Comment: Thank you dude! I watched the videos and I solved the problem, I was signing my app with an App Store Distribution Provisioning Profile, so I create a new Distribution Provisioning Profile for Ad Hoc distribution and it worked. :D

Answer (score 1):

Congrats on getting your first app up and running. Here are some links that may help:

1. http://www.oogtech.org/content/2010/09/12/iphone-dev-creating-ad-hoc-distributions-for-beta-testers/
2. http://www.paradeofrain.com/2010/11/taking-the-pain-out-of-ad-hoc-testing/

And, of course, this post on SO: [How do you beta test an iphone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154/how-do-you-beta-test-an-iphone-app)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/submitting-iphone-apps-to-the-apple-app-store-a-step-by-step-guide/), it is a step by step guide into the process. If you have never done it, be prepared, it's not a 5 minutes thing...