# iPhone - beta debugging with many distant users before publishing onto the AppStore

Tags: iphone, testing, app-store, publishing, beta

I have a completed application and I'd like to make it test by some friends before publishing it onto the AppStore. How may I do this without having to connect their phone onto my computer ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you beta test an iphone app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154/how-do-you-beta-test-an-iphone-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look here:

[How do you beta test an iphone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154/how-do-you-beta-test-an-iphone-app)

Comment: And be sure to look at the answer mentioning TestFlight.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using TestFlight. It streamlines this process for you allowing you to send out builds via email and it is free.

Check it out at http://www.testflightapp.com

Answer (score 0):

Here are some other options:

[iBetaTest](http://ibetatest.com/iphone/controllers/welcome/)

[TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/)

Answer (score -2):

Apple Developer Enterprise Program

http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: The Enterprise Program requires a registered company (i.e. no freelancers), costs $300 extra, and is totally unnecessary for beta testing an app. You can use ad-hoc distribution with the regular developer program for up to 100 testers.