# Test iPhone App on customers devices

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i have created an app for iphone, I also have a apple developer program certificate to compile my app.

Now I wont to send it to my customer to review. How can I do this? Did he need any certificate?

Thank yoU!

Comment: This link is a great starting point. Note that when you have it open there will be even more additional resource links on the right hand side that will help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154/how-do-you-beta-test-an-iphone-app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will need to go to the apple member center, and go to the provisioning portal.

You'll need to register every device there that wants to use the app.
For that you'll need the UDID (found in itunes, or with the app UDID sender).

Once you've done that you have to create your app-IDs (I usually take com.company.* so all apps with com.company are valid for that app-ID)

When you have done that you can create your provisioning certificate. That's what you'll need to install it on a device.

You can also have a look at [test flight app](https://testflightapp.com) which I use to send my demos to some clients.

Comment: second that - testflight for president! +1

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions given by apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action).
At first they may seem a lot, but if you do it step-by-step you'll see it's easy.
At least this is what i did!