# Iphone App Test Version

Tags: iphone, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Test iPhone App on customers devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939589/test-iphone-app-on-customers-devices)

I have a developer account for iPhone app development. I want to send a sample to my client, so that he can test on his device.

What is the procedure for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to upload to the AppStore, you'll need to add his DEVICE ID to the list of devices in your mobile provision.

[here's some documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html)

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the UDIDs of our clients and add those in the dev center.
2. Create a new ad hoc distribution profile and include all devices on which the app have to be tested and download the profile.
3. Drag the profile and drop it on the Xcode icon.
4. Add a new scheme with release build configuration and call it 'my app ad hoc'.
5. Chose in `Build Settings > Code Signing` the ad hoc profile you've just created.
6. In Xcode click `Product > Archive`. The Archive section of your Organizer in Xcode should open.
7. Click `share`. Under Identity chose the ad hoc profile again. Make sure `iOS App Store Package` is selected.
8. Click `Next`.
9. Insert the name of your app for storage and chose a directory where you want to save the ipa. Remember the directory for later reference.
10. Check the check box `Save for Enterprise Distribution`.
11. Include an url where you can put the ipa-file for download for your client. (Example http://www.mydomain.com/clientxy/myCoolApp.ipa)
12. Insert the name of your app and click `Save`.
13. Navigate to the directory from step 9. Create a file with the name `index.html` and insert the following:

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
>         "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
> <html>
> <head>
> <title>My Cool App</title>
> </head>
> <body>
> <ul>
>     <li><a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://www.mydomain.com/clientxy/myCoolApp.plist">Install my cool app</a></li>
> </ul>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Now put the .ipa, the .plist and the index.html to your server that they are reachable via the above url.

Your customer then have to navigate in safari with their iOS device to that url and click the the link.

The app will then be installed on your clients device.