# Transferring program from XCode to the iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I'm watching training videos on how to write code in XCode, but all the examples are for the simulator.  Right now I'm taking it on faith that I'll one day eventually transfer the bits over to my iPad, but I'd like to ask:

How can I transfer the program to my iPad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During development, use the Organizer that comes with XCode.  This question has also been answered - no surprise - on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154/how-do-you-beta-test-an-iphone-app).

Comment: Oh, here it is... It's Shift-Apple-2.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to sign up for an Apple Developer account for $99, and then once you do that, you can register your devices so that you can transfer over your iOS apps to your iOS devices (iPad, iPhone, iPod Touch) with XCode.  This is pretty much necessary once you get your apps completed, as the simulator and real iOS devices can handle apps differently and are needed for testing.

Comment: I have a developer account, but I have to register my devices too?

Comment: If you paid the Apple dev "dues," once you log in navigate to the "iOS Provisioning Portal."  They have a "Launch Assistant" that will guide you through the process.

Comment: use the organizer, command-shift-2, plug in the device, and set it as a developer device (the "registration" has been made easier with more recent - 4.x - versions of Xcode)

Answer (score 1):

You must register in the Apple Developer Program first (check http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action ) - it's about $100 per year.

Then follow the instructions there to create certificates, provisioning profiles, add devices and so on. They have all the info needed.

Comment: I see:     Articles,    Getting Started,    Guides,    Reference,
    Release Notes,    Sample Code,    Technical Notes,    Technical Q&As

But I don't see anything about registering devices.

Comment: So you log in there and then go to iOS Provisioning Portal(you must have a paid account to see that). After that you'll see everything.