# how to deploy an app to another ipad without usb connection?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, deployment, wireless

Is it possible to deploy an app on a friend's ipad for testing without the app being on the app store yet. My friend is far away so cannot connect to my mac via usb.

Answer (score 3):

If the UDID of your friends iPad is added to your developer account and you compiled the app with an Ad-Hoc distribution profile, you can just use the Product -> Export Menu Item in Xcode and email him the .ipa File. He can use iTunes to drop the file onto his iPad.

Another good solution to distribute beta versions of your software to testers and get feedback is [Testflight App](http://www.testflightapp.com)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to a similar question: [how do you beta test an iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154/how-do-you-beta-test-an-iphone-app).
Their question references iPhone, but the process should be the same for iPad.

Hope this helps!

Comment: One question, he doesn't have xcode, he will only test it, your answer still holds?

Comment: Your friend will only need iTunes and their iPad.  The answer will show you step-by-step instructions for what you must do to prepare your app for testing (quite lengthy, but very detailed and guides you through the entire process).  It also gives you the instructions you can send to your friend that tells them exactly how to install the app on their iPad.