# Xcode: How can I get my application on a friend's phone?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have made an app for my iphone.  I'm wanting to let my friend see the app too.  I've been loading the app onto my phone by selecting my iphone in Xcode and clicking "Run".  I cannot set his up to do this though since he's in another state.  Is there anyway I can set it up so he can load it on his phone?

Comment: Send him the code and have him do the same thing you are?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518261/how-to-deploy-an-app-to-another-ipad-without-usb-connection) might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/). You'll have to add his device to your account and create a new provisioning profile for his device, but then you can distribute it with TestFlight and automatically push out any updates to him.

Comment: I first made it into an ipa file. To do that I archived the project and then distributed it through the organizer. Then I was able to distribute it to his iphone thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't a way for you to share it wirelessly, but you could add his device to your account, and create a new provisioning profile with his device included, and he could download the project and run it there.

Comment: Actually there is. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4423913/427309, you can upload it to a server and then download it to the device.

Comment: my mistake. I thought there wasn't any way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Create an ad-hoc provisioning profile and use this profile to validate and distribute your app. Don't select App Store, but the other option (can't remember what that's called right now). This will create a .IPA file, which your friend can drag into iTunes and install on his device. Note that you will need to add his UDID to your developer portal for this to work.