# Questions about Ad Hoc distribution

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am trying to set an Ad Hoc distribution in order to test an iPhone app with some remote users. And I haven't found any good and clear tutorial up to now. By reading bits and pieces  on Apple documentation and others I am now  able to put the app on my iPod device doing as much as I can "as if I was remote user"; meaning I can put my app on the device without going through XCode. But when I send the xxx.mobileprovision an the app file to a remote user, things go wrong. The user gets a message saying that  there is no proper signing authority.

As far as I know I included myself and the other users in the list of device UDIDs.

One thing unclear to me related to this issue is :
In the iOS Provisioning Portal section Certificates I can see one tab "Development" and another one "Distribution", I am not sure of what the difference is. I have one item in each tab, but I see no "Add" button to add more items and try something different. Is one of those two tabs important for my problem above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The tabs are very important.

With certificates, Development is the Key Chain cert that grants you permission to build in Xcode directly to an iOS device connected by cable. Distribution is the Key Chain cert that grants you permission to build in Xcode app that may be installed onto an iOS device remotely.

Development is the  mobile provisioning profile that has the list of registered an iOS devices you may directly build an app onto connected by cable.

Distribution is the  mobile provisioning profile that has the list of registered an iOS devices you may send an app to someone else and have them install it on a registered iOS device remotely without using Xcode.

You want to do an Archive which will require a Distribution mobile provisioning profile. I might add that if you are sending an mobile provisioning profile in an email, you will likely want to Zip it with the .ipa since the profile can often get corrupted with in certain email clients.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to another question that has very thorough step-by-step instructions for creating ad-hoc distribution profiles: [how do you beta test an iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154/how-do-you-beta-test-an-iphone-app).  The instructions have changed slightly with newer Xcode versions, but this is still the best walkthrough I could find.