# OTA beta testing on iOS 5

Tags: ios, udid

OK, I have read this page: [How do you beta test an iphone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154/how-do-you-beta-test-an-iphone-app)

It does a nice job explaining how to send your app to beta testers out there. The only problem is this: to generate the ad-hoc profile I need the tester's device ID, but how do I do that with people that don't have any computer to sync the device, in other words, people that could use iTunes to discover their device ID.

How can users know their device ID just using the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some apps on the App Store that you can tell users to download - [namely this one](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ad-hoc-helper/id285691333?mt=8)

Another really great option is to go and create a free account at [TestFlightApp.com](http://www.testflightapp.com). You can then invite friends to sign up for free accounts which will install a web app on their phone which reports UDID back to the Test Flight dashboard. Checkout Test Flight as it will surely ease your beta testing.

Comment: thanks, but how this will happen in the future if apple is deprecating the UDID?

Comment: I believe the UDID will always be required for creating provisioning profiles, but it won't be used for identifying users of the app.

Comment: just one final question? I see now that there's no need to send the user the provisioning profile anymore. Is this correct? Thanks

Comment: When you're ready to distribute the app to your beta testers, select iOS Device from the Scheme and choose Product->Archive from the menu. At that point the Organizer Window will open up (if it isn't already) and you click the "Share" button. This allows you to re-sign the app bundle (if you want) with a provisioning profile that differs from what it was built with (i.e. Some developers have a "developer" profile and a beta testers profile). It will then create an .ipa file that you upload to Test Flight (or email out and they drop into iTunes).

Comment: thanks. I thought it was necessary to mail the tester the provisioning profile too.