# Testing iOS Ad-hoc IPA on iCloud synced devices

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, icloud, ipa

I have to send a test build (IPA) to my client, but my client is using iCloud to sync his apps/music on iPhone (no iTunes). The only way I knew to test ah-hoc IPA is sync it using iTunes.

Is there any way that my client could test my build, which doesn't effects his iCloud sync (apps, music or app data)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/) is also another good choice to do that.

I've used it and found it very helpful in managing releases, teams and testers.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40154/593709) is very useful discussion.

Comment: Thanks your answer, I'm not intrested in using TestFlight, but other link you referred was helpful.

Comment: @Zee TestFlight is free and almost completely streamlines the process for you and especially your testers (they get an email and press the install button it)

Comment: @Jonathan. Much thanks, I would definitely give a try to TestFlight next time :)

Answer (score 0):

This was the best and to the point solution of this problem which I found.

[Install Ad-hoc/Test-builds from Web](http://www.paradeofrain.com/2010/11/taking-the-pain-out-of-ad-hoc-testing/)