# Don't show notifications when use profile provisioning

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I use profile developer, sent notify, my application receive notify normal. But I use profile provisioning. I create file .p12 from Apple Product IOS Push Services and private key. When I send message use this .p12, application doesn't receive notify.

Answer (score 0):

If you use profile provisioning, you can only receive notifications in app from appStore. Profile developer is only used for test.

Comment: I build my application used profile provisioning, and get token. Then, i used file .p12 send notify to this token. My application don't receive notify. Because my application will upload to appstore, but now it don't run notification. Can you help me?

Comment: the only way to test your notification by production provisioning before upload to appstore is use Ad Hoc. you can see this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154/how-do-you-beta-test-an-iphone-app/2426270#2426270](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154/how-do-you-beta-test-an-iphone-app/2426270#2426270)

Comment: you have no other way. you can only test developer certification notification now or build beta to test Production certification.

Comment: i used profile Ad Hoc, and add devices. But after get token and use .p12 Apple Product IOS Push Services send notify. My app don't receive.