# How to submit to iTunes Connect in XCode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, macos

This must be the worst question ever asked.

I'm almost ashamed to ask it but I can't wrap my head around this.

We are trying to push my app to itunes connect for beta testing.
Now there is no way to do this because XCode 6 gives all signing errors available.
We are able to run the app on the development device just as usual. We have the profiles.

But when we set the release sign identity to iOS Distribution, the hell breaks loose.
No matching identity was the first error. Fix issue releases another error:

```
No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity were found.
```

It's useful to note that XCode knows this better than I do so it changes the code signing identity back to developer.
That's not me, I want to distribute.

Ok so at this time we're stuck at this error. We don't know where it came from, but we do know there was another error.

While pressing the submit button in the organizer the error was:

```
"You already have a valid provisioning profile"
```

According to the apple documentation I should press the revoke & request button but that isn't there.

So here we are, totally stuck and have no idea where to go now. The apple docs are incomplete, the signing gives errors but no logs. Errors messages change, but are consistent.

What the hell should we do now?
Reinstall OSX and remove all existing profiles? What will happen with current clients running apps on those profiles?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in yoru account and check that the provisioning profiles are active and not invalid.  You might need to regenerate it.

You might also want to download them manually and install them yourself.

Sometimes I've had to archive the app then submit 'manually' using application loader.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going back to basics:

- check your development and distribution profiles on the developer site. if you have recently renewed your annual subscription, you might need to recreate them.
- when you are archiving make sure you chose the real testing device, not a simulator.

if both doesn't work, create a new empty project and sign it with the profiles and archive. if that works, then check if you altered the bundle settings. if it doesn't work, delete your profiles and recreate them.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I understand the plight of having to deal with the overly complex process of app submission which should have been rather simple.

Two things:

1. Make sure you delete all the provisioning profiles. Revoke and request a new one. Create a new certificate with distribution licence (you can make upto 3).
2. Once you've done that go to tour XCode > Preferences > Accounts and open up the apple id you find there. Refresh and that should download and fix redundancies.

For more I think you should also give this a read.
[How do you beta test an iphone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154/how-do-you-beta-test-an-iphone-app)

About you second issue. What would happen to apps packed with previous profiles?
Well, your app is not bundled with a particular profile and so you can create a new one and use that without pain