# How to test a iPhone app on my device with developer team member?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm a iOS beginner. I receive a invitation with team member.
So I accepted the invitation. Now I'm trying to test a iPhone app on my device.
But I can't see the team account in Xcode account.
There is only my free developer account (Personal Team).
What do I do if I test with team account member?

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice. If you're going to post it again to make changes, take down the first one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debugging a iPhone app on my device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427369/how-to-debugging-a-iphone-app-on-my-device)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you beta test an iphone app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154/how-do-you-beta-test-an-iphone-app)