# How to debugging a iPhone app on my device?

Tags: ios, xcode, account

I'm a iOS beginner. I received a invitation with team member. So I accepted the invitation and I'm trying to test a iPhone app on my device. But I can't see the team account in Xcode account. There is only my free developer account (Personal Team) in xcode account. What do I do if I test with team account member?

Comment: Please do not repost your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to sign in to their Apple ID (with the Developer account) in Xcode.

Go to Xcode->Preferences->Accounts and add a new account. You will need the email and password.

The team should appear in the drop down list option of the general settings of the project.