# How to remove a Run Script phase from Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I tried this step:

Select the menu options "Project > New Build Phase > New Run Script Build Phase", and enter the following script (don't forget to replace /Users/youruser/bin by the correct path to gen_entitlements.py) :

```
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
if [ "${PLATFORM_NAME}" == "iphoneos" ]; then
    /Users/youruser/bin/gen_entitlements.py "my.company.${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}/${PROJECT_NAME}.xcent";
    codesign -f -s "iPhone developer" --resource-rules "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}/ResourceRules.plist" \
         --entitlements "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}/${PROJECT_NAME}.xcent"  "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}/"
fi
```

(from [link](http://www.246tnt.com/iPhone/#xcode))

Now I want to remove this script from my project. How do I remove the "Run Script Build Phase" build phase from Xcode?

Comment: Seems almost exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-real-iphone-device ?

Comment: The problem is how to remove the scripts added at "Project > New Build Phase > New Run Script Build Phase"

Answer (score 24):

Select the Run Script phase in your target and delete it.

[image: Delete]

Answer (score 6):

for xcode 4.5.1, the appearance is slightly different, click once on the run script phase and simultaneously press function + backspace (on a mac) to delete. When the dialog box pops up, click delete.[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. In the Project Navigator go to the upper left hand corner and select the blue icon

[image]

2. In the top center of the screen select `Build Phases`

[image]

3. When you see the `Run Script` that you want to delete look all the way on the right hand corner of it and you'll see an `X`

[image]

4. Press the `X` and you'll see a menu appear asking if you want to delete it

[image]

5. Choose `Delete`