# Remove fabric framework from ios app

Tags: ios, twitter-fabric

I have been landed an iOS project from a client. The main task is to explore and see the user interface so that multiplatform app will be made from scratch with Xamarin.

I notice that the project uses third party framework called fabric. From what i see it is used from crash analytics. I don't need that and i don't have registration so i want to remove all dependencies from the project.

So far I did:

1. Deleted `define ENABLE_FABRIC` ( which removed some code from
   AptDelegate, replaced logging messages with plain NSLog etc)
2. Removed some fabric script invocation from build phases
3. Removed reference from fabric framework in project

So i still have errors building my app:

> /bin/sh:
>   /Users/macmini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/../Build/Intermediates/../Script-FDC6FCE81A4488D000F2613D.sh:
>   (null): bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Does anyone know a quick way to get rid of this?

Comment: It sounds as if there's a build script defined for the project.  Check your target's build phases for a Run Script phase with a problem.

Answer (score 14):

I know it's an old question but I want to help. When you install Fabric, previously Crashlytics, it asks you to put a script in project->Build Phases-> Run Script

it will look like this

./Fabric.framework/run 123456fd7ec....6e2170Q

I think you should remove that script and other Linked Frameworks and Libraries and then it possibly could run

Comment: I don't work on this project anymore so I can't validate that. However I described in my question that i removed that script invokation :)

Comment: This is it!! This solved my problem. Thank you for taking time answering an old question! Still relevant for me in 2018.

Comment: This works, Here are some visual directions to delete a Run Script https://stackoverflow.com/a/48738485/4833705

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the files `DerivedData` path and clean build folder

`cmd+opt+shift+k`

then re run the application.

Also check once again the Framework search path in xcode settings.

Comment: Actually when i delete DerivedData it creates itself automatically. Even if I close XCode when i run it again it still creates the dervived data folder.

Comment: yes it will creates the DerivedData folder. Delete once and then clean the build and run it again