# How to deploy iPhone Application on iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have created one application using XCode.

Now i want to deploy that application into iPhone. Can any one have any links or solutions for that ? Thanks...

Comment: For testing, ad-hoc distribution, app store distribution, or enterprise distribution? I think it matters...

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-real-iphone-device

Comment: @Brad it may be a duplicate of the question, but the question was asked last October (2008)!  This means that actually the answers in the question you link to (have you even looked at it??) are utterly different; the replies say either "you must jailbreak" or "you can't".  Please check the links you provide in future before just mindlessly saying "This is a duplicate"... grrrr :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pay the $99 (or local currency equivalent) annual fee to Apple to join the developer programme.

This will enable you to:

- Test on actual devices that you own
- Put the application on up to 100 devices for testing or running without going through the iTunes app store (this is called "ad hoc" distribution)
- Submit the application to Apple for inclusion in their store

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi. Once our developer certificate is expired, do we need to pay another 99$ to extend it? Can we still upload the apps to iphone if we don't extend it?

Comment: Yes, you will need to pay another $99.  Any certificates you have created while it was still active will soon expire, and then you will have no way of getting your apps either on a single iPhone or uploaded to the Apple store.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test your application on an iPhone/iPod Touch or sell it via the App Store, you need to purchase a iPhone Developer Membership (€ 79,- / Year). See [the iPhone Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone) for details. Once you are a paying member, the website also offers more information about how to deploy an application.