# Develop native applications and load application onto iphone/ipod

Tags: iphone

It is possible to  develop native applications and load application onto iphone/ipod devices before paying a Apple Developer Connection membership fee?If anybody knows please give me some idea about that.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-real-iphone-device

Answer (score 1):

No, not unless you have a jailbroken phone.  You can download the SKD and test in the simulator for free, but to test on a device, you need to pay.