# How can I test my iphone app on actual device?

Tags: iphone, xcode, code-signing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I deploy an iPhone Application from Xcode to real iPhone device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-real-iphone-device)

Is there any other way rather than pay $99 and get the keypair?

3.1.3 device, 3.2.2/3.2 XCode/sdk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I deploy an iPhone application from Xcode to a real iPhone device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-real-iphone-device)

Answer (score 0):

Jailbreak your iPhone and SSH your app onto it.