# Developing a private iPhone tethering app

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Recently, an app was [released](http://www.engadget.com/2010/07/20/handy-light-for-iphones-dirty-little-secret-tethering-video/) on the AppStore that secretly allowed wifi-tethering from your iPhone. It quickly got pulled by Apple. Out of curiosity, are there any libraries for the iPhone SDK that helps developers write an application that does the same thing? I'm assuming you can deploy the app to your iPhone for testing purposes without publishing to the AppStore is that correct?

**UPDATE**

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-real-iphone-device/866570#866570) as I was writing the question, so it looks like deploying the app to your own iPhone is not a problem as long as you have a developer certificate. So my only question then is regarding any libraries or code examples that can help with this tethering/proxy solution.

Comment: I'm sure Apple has made this very hard, but I'll just say that it's possible on jailbroken devices, as MyWi (http://rockyourphone.com/index.php/mywi.html) has consistently provided WiFi and USB tethering across many iOS versions.

Comment: @seanny94 Thanks for the info. However, I'm not really interested in any arbitrary solution to tethering on the iPhone, I'm more interested in the development process and what components need to work together to make it happen. Just a hobby to see if I can make it work!

Comment: Also, since an app which does so has already appeared on the AppStore I'm sure it is possible to do myself for fun.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

looks like there's some open source code already posted - https://github.com/tcurdt/iProxy/wiki

Comment: That just provides a HTTP & SOCKS proxy on your iPhone. **Completely** different from tethering.