# How to deploy xcode application in real device

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone. I am developing a simple application in iphone 3.1.2. Now I need to test it on a real device. But I am not in a position to pay $99. Is there any alternate way to test my application on a real device.

Please advice any other way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I deploy an iPhone Application from Xcode to real iPhone device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-real-iphone-device)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to [jailbreak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking) your device so that you can [by-pass the code signatures](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/03/29/bypass-code-signature-published-your-application-on-cydia/), this is how apps are developed for and deployed on [Cydia](http://cydia.saurik.com/).