# Xcode 4 and jailbroken iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, sdk, jailbreak

I've just purchased Xcode 4 and am trying to develop my apps in it. I don't currently have a developers license however (and don't want one until I am ready to submit to the app store) so I have jailbroken my device and installed appsync.

After following the steps suggested [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-real-iphone-device), not only can I not deploy to my iPhone, but now any project I create for iPhoneOS, I get the warning;

```
Target Integrity
Missing SDK in target XXXXX: iphoneos
```

I don't know enough about `sed` to know what went on during the steps when I was trying to get it work so my question has two parts really:

1. How do I restore Xcode to its previous state so I can use the iOS SDK (Really don't want to have to download 4+GB from Apple again).
2. How do I configure Xcode **4** to deploy to my jailbroken iPhone for testing. ( I should have previously mentioned that I had everything working in Xcode 3.2 an I have already tried deleted and recreating the self signed certificate as iPhone Developer).

**EDIT**
I removed the warnings that I didn't didn't have the SDK by simply reverting to the backup file that `sed` generated.

**EDIT 2**
Should have played about a bit more before asking here I guess... I recreated another developer certificate and replace the relevant contents of the `SDKSettings.plist` with this:

```
            <key>AD_HOC_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED</key>
            <string>YES</string>
            <key>CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED</key>
            <string>NO</string>
            <key>CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>DEAD_CODE_STRIPPING</key>
            <string>YES</string>
            <key>ENTITLEMENTS_REQUIRED</key>
            <string>NO</string>
```

And it all works! However, I am unable to debug as I can't find the `Project > New Build Phase > New Run Script Build Phase` option in the new XCode layout. Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: I'm at the same point as you (after updating the post you're talking about). It works! But no debugging as well. Sorry I can't help you, but maybe you get lucky [in here](http://brandontreb.com/beginning-jailbroken-ios-development-getting-the-tools/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i see in [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-real-iphone-device/4180498#4180498), which I guess you followed, the steps proposed are clean and each time backuping original files. So for your first question, just restore original files :

- `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Info.plist.bak`
- `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/SDKSettings.plist.bak`
- `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/iPhoneOS Build\ System Support.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/iPhoneOS Build System Support.original`

**EDIT** : Run build phase is now there, in project preferences :
[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. That is indeed what I had done but I appreciate the clarification.Whenever I try to run the app on the device however, I get the error:

Comment: I'm actually flattered by all this! :)

Answer (score 0):

Give [Jailcoder](http://jailcoder.com) a try, it automates the whole process