# How do i build an iphone app that installs on a jailbreaked Iphone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, jailbreak

I am a registered apple developer, and I want to install my application on a jailbreaked iphone.
My question is If i register the device for development and create the provisioning report and app built following the normal steps will i be able to install the application on the jaibreaked divice. If not please tell me how to install my app on a jailbreaked Iphone.

Comment: possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802389/xcode-4-and-jailbroken-iphone

Comment: Is it Jailbreaked or Jailbroken :?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also install on a jailbreak iOS Device using XCode or iTunes (the normal way).
The jailbreak won't break your Xcode installation/deployment possibilities.