# Iphone application developing under VMWare

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

I've been working on iPhone application for quite a while now, and, I've came to a point where I should test my application on actual iPhone Device.
I have Mac OS X 10.6.6 Server Edition working on VMWare 7. I'm using XCode 4.
As I don't have iPhone myself, I've tried connecting my college's.
However, it's not getting recognized.
On the other hand, if I connect it on my host (which is Windows 7), it opens as Apple Device and I get access to internal storage.
iPhone is 3GS iOS version 4.3.3. 
Can anyone give me any idea how to solve this before I go and buy Developer's licence?
Thanks.

**Edit:** Sorry for not being clear about my question / problem. Thing is that I couldn't connect my any USB device to Mac, and I was asking how to solve that problem. Other part of my question was - how can I test my application on iPhone without paying to apple for Developer license.
First part I've solved - I updated OS X to 10.6.7 and installed MultiBeast.
Second part - I've installed my app using Cyndia (packed it into deb file, transferred it to phone, used terminal app to install it) -however, it couldn't start.

Comment: you pass in USB to OS X?

Comment: No Mac, no iPhone, no intention to buy a cheap developer license... *maybe* iOS is not the right choice for you.

Comment: "Can anyone give me any idea how to solve this before I go and buy Developer's licence?". As you might imagine - I will buy it, after I make sure everything is okey. I find it kinda funny that you have to pay 1000$ (computer+phone+dev. license) to company to start developing software for their OS, but that's another discussion.

Comment: A $99 developers license is probably the best thing you could do for both yourself and your client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install application on device, you have *officially* to apply (pay) to Apple developer program.

There are also *not so official* workarounds involving jailbreak and patching iOS system files, which is not really easy to do...

I hope that was the question :)

---

**EDIT**

About your second part :

1. Install from cydia some package named something like `syslogs` and do something like `tail -f /var/log/system.log` to understand why app fails to start. *(all from memory, didn't checked)*
2. Most probable error is that your binary is not signed properly. The quick&cheap solution is to use `ldid -S my binary` there is a cydia package I guess. *(again, memory, see [that link](http://www.saurik.com/id/8) for more details)*
3. The best solution *if you really don't want to pay $99 but waste hours to do a complex set up (full of workarounds, patchs and such...)*, and get the "Build & go" of Xcode like you were paying... Give a look [at this](http://www.alexwhittemore.com/?p=398).

---

**EDIT 2**

Give a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-real-iphone-device) for more details, what I've wrote in my previous edit is mostly there.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it is more or less the question, as I've clarified now :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It's really helpful. I will go and buy that developer's license ASAP. As far as app not starting - it does like start, but crashes (closes) right after. I will try methods for debugging you've suggested. Thanks again. Really helpful.