# Distribute iOS apps without joining Developer Program

Tags: ios, ipad, deployment, distribution, apple-developer

I wrote a simple app. I'm not in "iOS Developer Program", i.e. I cannot publish on AppStore. But I would like to show the app to a friend who as an iPad. How can I manage to do it? Does the friends needs to jail-break his iPad? Is it possible that someone else who is in the "Program" will publish the app for me?

Comment: Check this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-real-iphone-device

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cydia Impactor to install unsigned apps onto the “jailed” iPad. The app will only be available for two weeks until it has to be resigned with Cydia Impactor.

https://www.shoutpedia.com/use-cydia-impactor-install-ipa-apps-iphone-without-jailbreak/

Answer (score 0):

If you friends has jail-breaken iPad, you can make ipa-file and install on his device. You can make ipa-file with command "Build&Archive" in XCode 3.x or "Archive" in XCode 4.
And you have no ways to install your app on not jail-breaken devices without iOS Developer Program.

Comment: Ok, thanks and how do I upload that "ipa-file" into a jail-broken iPad?