# iOS app can't be launched on iOS 5

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios5

My app is a deb file built with iOS 4.3 SDK. It's self certified.
The development environment confirm to [How can I deploy an iPhone application from Xcode to a real iPhone device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-real-iphone-device/4180498#4180498)

The app can run on jailbroken iOS 4.3 device.

However, it can't be launched on jailbroken iOS 5.0 now.

The log is:

Oct 9 14:46:38 ibmmato-iPod SpringBoard[1891] : Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 1917: (os/kern) failure

Oct 9 14:46:38 ibmmato-iPod com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.gmail.rwx.rwx[0x885a][1917]) : (UIKitApplication:com.gmail.rwx.rwx[0x885a]) Exited: Killed: 9

Oct 9 14:46:38 ibmmato-iPod com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.gmail.rwx.rwx[0x885a]) : (UIKitApplication:com.gmail.rwx.rwx[0x885a]) Throttling respawn: Will start in 2147483647 seconds

Oct 9 14:46:38 ibmmato-iPod SpringBoard[1891] : Application \'abcd\' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9

Oct 9 14:46:38 ibmmato-iPod kernel[0] : Sandbox: hook..execve() killing pid 1917: outside of container && !i_can_has_debugger

Oct 9 14:46:41 ibmmato-iPod SpringBoard[1891] : Posting \'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus\' notifyState=0

Oct 9 14:46:41 ibmmato-iPod SpringBoard[1891] : MultitouchHID: detection mode: 0->255

Comment: iOS 5 is still NDA until public release on Wednesday 12th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to humour me - restart eh phone and Xcode.   When I get this error that fixes it.

Comment: I tried. But the problem is still there...