# Creating iphone App for personal use without uploading to AppStore

Tags: iphone

I am planning to do an app for personal use only (I don't want to upload anywhere, ex: AppStore)

**Is it possible to build one and transfer + install it to my jailbroken IpodTouch?**

I just want to make sure it is possible so I don't waste my time creating an app that I can't use ('cause I am not paying $99 to upload it on the AppStore)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I deploy an iPhone application from Xcode to a real iPhone device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-real-iphone-device)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a guide for making build & go and build & debug work with a jailbroken iPhone/iPod touch.

It is written for Xcode 3.2.1 and iPhone OS 3.1.2 so I don't know if it works with the newer versions.

http://www.alexwhittemore.com/?p=354

Comment: interesting... Thanks I will try that :D

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using an online tool like Recoil App Builder or Snappii.  Snappii is more AppStore oriented, but their pricing is pretty reasonable.  Recoil is free and allows you to install the app on your phone instantly without going through any AppStore hurdles.

Links to App Builders:

http://www.recoilapp.com/

https://www.snappii.com/pricing

Btw, regardless of how you make your app, I do NOT recommend jailbreaking your phone.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pay the $99 to get it on your phone in the first place. Sorry.

Comment: Are you sure? But it is jailbroken, I can easily transfer files and stuff, I hope you are wrong :(

Comment: Sorry; I'm not all that knowledgeable about jailbroken devices, but officially, you do have to pay.

Answer (score 0):

You can if you get an app provisioning profile. or Jailbreak, if a jailbreak isn't available for your device iPhone5(s) iPad 4 and Air, mini and retina. You can just purchase a provisioning profile from some other place usually $8-$15 mine was $14 able to load them nicely without paying apple $100 just to get your feet wet.