# Building and deploying Iphone App on a real device without apple developer program and any certificates

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Xcode 4.2.1
Lion

Jailbraked Iphone

Main problem is that I cannot find my country in the list of countryies while updating my credit cards info. Thus probably I cannot buy that 99$ program membership.

But I want to make the app anyway, at list to try , on a real iphone.

Here
[Test iOS app on device without apple developer program or jailbreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak)

WrightsCS Writes this

```
There's a way you can do this.

You will need ROOT access to edit the following file.

Navigation to /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk and open the file SDKSettings.plist.

In that file, expand DefaultProperties and change CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED to NO, while you are there, you can also change ENTITLEMENTS_REQUIRED to NO also.

You will have to restart Xcode for the changes to take effect. Also, you must do this for every .sdk you want to be able to run on device.

Now, in your project settings, you can change Code Signing Identity to Don't Code Sign.

Your app should now build and install on your device successfully.
```

I've done it but get error of the following type

```
Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain
```

/
/
/
/
/

I've also read about this
[How can I deploy an iPhone application from Xcode to a real iPhone device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-real-iphone-device)
Where rpetrich writes

```
It sounds like the application isn't signed. Download ldid from Cydia and then use it like so: ldid -S /Applications/AccelerometerGraph.app/AccelerometerGraph

Also be sure that the binary is marked as executable: chmod +x /Applications/AccelerometerGraph.app/AccelerometerGraph
```

But it was in 2008. And when I started to look for this Idid and things, in comments there where posts that with new soft it doesn't work. So I even didn't try it.

SO....

Today. Is there any way out of this problem ?

Comment: This is probably not relevant to you anymore, but to follow up with some recent developments, Apple announced free device provisioning w/ Xcode 7 in WWDC2015. Check out this link for details - https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH27-SW3

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the only way to "legitimately" install any apps on a device is to have a developer account. Provisioning profiles and your developer certificate must be used to sign the app in order to install to the device.

Answer (score 0):

You can install self-signed or pseudo signed (with ldid) apps on a jailbroken phone (Not otherwise). Check out the presentation on how this can be done at http://www.priyaontech.com/download/12/