# Not able to test my app on jailbroken device

Tags: iphone, ios

I had followed this methid to test my app on jailbroken device using this guide:[How can I deploy an iPhone application from Xcode to a real iPhone device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-real-iphone-device)
Now I am getting this error
Check dependencies

[BEROR]CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'Device - iOS 4.1'
i have disabled code sign (as per guide) but still getting the error
someone please help?

Comment: do you have a apple ios developer account?

Comment: No. I wanto run in jailbroken device

Comment: can you provide more info? did you do all steps? did all steps completed sucessfully? you seem to have stopped in the first one.