# Where is "Developer" folder?

Tags: vmware, xcode4.3

I want to learn how to develop for iOS devices, but I don't have a Mac, so I virtualise OS X with VMWare.

I'm just beginning in Objective-C, so I just made a simple view with a button. I built my first project into the simulator, and that works fine, but I want to use my iPod for developing.

I know this issue was fixed in others topics, but I have a problem.
I don't have any folder named "Developer" in the root directory of my HDD (and so, I can't do "cd /Developer/"...)

How is this possible? I'm sorry if my question is stupid, but I'm really a beginner in the Mac environment.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since version 4.3 Xcode is a single app in your Application Folder.
Before 4.3 Xcode was located in `/Developer`. That has changed, you can find the "developer folder" inside of the app package. Try `cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/`.

You didn't say why you need to be in that folder so I don't know if you will find what you are looking for. It is possible that files have been moved to different locations.

Comment: Thanks, I found the folder.
in fact, I'v made these steps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-real-iphone-device

But, at each lines, I had "Directory not found"
So, I don't think this solution is yet avaible, so how can I patch my Xcode ?

Comment: replace the `/Developer/` part in each command with `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/`. You could possibly create a symbolic link at `/Developer` that links inside the app bundle too. After `sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ /Developer` you should be able to access `/Developer`