# Deploying iOS App in Xcode 4.3+ without certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, ipod, cordova

**Hello all!**

I want to test how my Cordova-ported apps run on real device, and if I like performance, I'll buy Apple Developer Certificate. But now I dont want to waste hundred bucks just to see my webapps running slow and ugly as shit. I've looked through all that forums and also here on stackoverflow, and all solutions seem to relate to iOS SDK 4.2 and earlier.

And what about **Xcode 4.3+**?

I've edited /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/SDKSettings.plist and also turned out code signing in project settings.

I've got two **MyProject.app**'s from "Build for Running" and "Build for Archiving" and tried to sync them to my iPod touch 4 via iTunes, but in both cases app **crashes** immediately after launch.

I also extracted **.ipa** from iTunes and tried to install it via Installous, but got the same problem. Thing crashes.

I also got **.xcarchive** via Product->Archive but don't know what is to be done next with it..

So, question is here: how can I deploy my own app to my own jailbroken iPod touch?

**Thank you.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-real-iphone-device

Comment: I read that thread but seems like there is no solution for my Xcode 4.3, answers is too old :(

Comment: btw, I went through running on my iPod straight from Xcode, but it also crashes with different logs:
--
error: failed to launch '/Users/zinchuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-hifviqryhgehgifeybzdvontcudh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HelloWorld.app/HelloWorld' -- failed to get the task for process 1170
--
error: failed to launch '/Users/zinchuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjCTest-ghfujgyktkznlzcsrhmswhxoboey/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ObjCTest.app/ObjCTest' -- failed to send the qLaunchSuccess packet
-- (here I tryed to test ObjC default app, with the same result)

Comment: did you fake code sign the application after building in Xcode?  I use the method rpetrich suggests in the accepted answer in mkral's link, fake signing with `ldid`.  then, you can `scp` the entire app bundle to your device, and install it in /Applications.

Comment: I didn't get, where have i to run ldid command? I donwloaded that tool from Cydia, and run it from OpenSSH:
--
Ajaxy-iPod:/var/mobile/Applications/EE69FFCD-224F-44B6-8B69-28FBB6134461 root# chmod +x ObjCTest.app/ObjCTest
Ajaxy-iPod:/var/mobile/Applications/EE69FFCD-224F-44B6-8B69-28FBB6134461 root# ldid -S ObjCTest.app/ObjCTest
**util/ldid.cpp(567): _assert(78:arch != NULL)**
--
I don't know if it's an error, but app still crashes :( Am I to create Self-Signed Certificate as described below on that link?

Comment: Just tried scp + ldid for Cordova apps, got another error:
--
codesign_allocate: for architecture armv6 object: MasterMind.app/MasterMind malformed object (unknown load command 8)
util/ldid.cpp(582): _assert(78:WEXITSTATUS(status) == 0)
--

Comment: Maybe the cause is that I'm using iPod touch instead of iPhone?
And what build button i have to use? among these: http://ajaxy.ru/mm/buildwtf.png

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to take a look at JailCoder.

It allows you to Debug your app made with XCode on a real device without a developer account.

Please keep in mind such solution should only be temporary. If it runs well and you want to do further developing / deployment consider buying a Developer account.

Comment: I mean I've bought a Developer account )

Comment: Why would you flag this answer as wrong ? Please give more details on your issue if this did not answer you former question for future readers

Answer (score 0):

On jailbroken iDevices, Cydia (and other dpkg installers) install apps to /private/Applications/

So why not try:
/Applications/MyProject.app

Then open a terminal on the device and navigate to /Applications:
chmod -777 MyProject.app
chown root MyProject.app

Comment: I don't understand how it can help.