# Testing on jailbroken brand-new iOS device - using Xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, jailbreak, provisioning-profile

OK. So, here's some details on my situation :

- I've got a brand-new **iPhone 4**.
- The iOS version has been updated to **5.1.1** (9B206).
- The phone has been **jailbroken** using *redsn0w*.
- I'm running **Lion (10.7.4)** and **Xcode 4.3**.

Now, my issue :

- I'm creating a sample test app, which runs fine under the simulator.
- Followed everything [here](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices), but without any result.
- Also tried enabling my device via Organizer ("Use as development device").

When I click on "Use as development device", it keeps saying...

> The version of iOS on “Dr.Kameleon’s iPhone” does not match any of the
>   versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of
>   the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed
>   below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is
>   available here.
>
> OS Installed on Dr.Kameleon’s iPhone
>   5.1.1 (9B206)
>
> Xcode Supported iOS Versions Latest
>   5.0 (9A334)
>   4.3
>   4.2

While, when I try running on my "iOS device" (that's how it appears), it claims there's no device with a proper iOS version.

> No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS
>   version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to
>   run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

Any ideas? What's going wrong?

Comment: If you wanna test on a JB'en device, youd'd better just scp over the final app bundle...

Comment: Try to drag the app bundle into iTunes then synchronize.

Comment: You do realize that Xcode is just doing what Apple does best: keeping you from doing things they don't want you too. There's no way that they would let Xcode install to a Jailbroken device. Also, do you have a developer's licence?

Comment: @AlexSalom I'll try this right now...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy

Comment: @Linuxios Well, I do realize that; although when it comes to something I'm such a newbie, I tend to thing that it's me who's doing something wrong... lol. (Yep, sure I have license; I've been a Mac / iPhone dev for over a year, though I haven't really "played" with iPhone yet...)

Comment: @H2CO3 Aha... ok, got it! ;-)

Comment: @Linuxios That's definitely not true! 1. Apple's software doesn't tend to event try to brick your device if it's jailbroken 2. Why not release apps for JB'en devices? Lots of developers make a living from it...

Comment: @H2CO3: Really? I though iTunes would brick your device if you jailbroke it. And people sell jailbroken apps? I take back all I said.

Comment: @Linuxios No. iTunes doesn't even have a way to detect JB -- Apple pretends it doesn't even know what JB is. And yes, they do sell them -- google IntellBorn, Ryan Petrich, Filippo Bigarella and the like.

Comment: The problem is you don't have the SDK for 5.1, only 5.0.  I'm guessing your simulator is "iPhone 5.0 Simulator" not "iPhone 5.1 Simulator".  Try downloading the newest SDK (public, not developer beta).  Also, another thought, do you have a developer license?  You have to have a developer license to use xcode to test on devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, everyone who says you can't build directly on a jailbroken device is wrong. You can, and it's quite easy to do. If you don't have a provisioned device (and it looks like you don't), using [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4180498/862536) will work. I've tested it myself on Lion running Xcode 4.3 (it even works on later versions, but those are under NDA).

The real issue seems to be that, for whatever reason, you don't have the iOS 5.1 SDK - you're using the iOS 5.0 SDK. You can confirm this by looking in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs` and `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`. If you don't see any mention of 5.1, you don't have it installed. Try downloading and installing Xcode again (I believe it's 4.3.2 now), which should have the iOS 5.1 SDK bundled with it.

Comment: Thanks mate! I'm not that familiar with iPhone dev (I mean on real devices), so I was a bit frustrated with this whole thing, thinking that I was doing something wrong. The thing is, that I did exactly what you suggested - as simple as that - and, of course, it's working! :-)

Answer (score 2):

This error is not due to the jailbroken iPhone, its basically due to your lower version of Xcode which doesn't support the latest iOS, try upgrading your Xcode version to latest.
hope it helps