# How can i install and test my app on jailbroken iDevice without developer account?

Tags: ios, installation, jailbreak

I want to test my app on real device (jailbroken).
But, i have no developer account.
How can i install and test my app on device?
Please, suggest me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I deploy an iPhone application from Xcode to a real iPhone device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-real-iphone-device)

Answer (score 3):

You do not need a developer account for jailbroken devices.

Simply download from your Mac to your device and test your apps.

For more [information](http://www.alexwhittemore.com/developing-jailbroken-iphone-iphone-312/).